# Fastest Method for 'Simple' Clustering?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

In a recent adult education class I took the prof shared a spreadsheet that was written in `VBA` code and takes ages to execute, I'm sure `Python` (`SciPy`, `Pandas`, `Numpy`) can handle this much faster.

The problem is a Direct Clustering Algorithm (DCA) one, all the searches I've done to solve this keep showing solutions trying to use `K-mean` which is not applicable.

The x-axis is different manufactured parts, and the y-axis are the different machines used in the manufacturing of the parts. `0 = not used`, `1 = used`.

**The best description I can come up with is this:  It's trying to make as clean a diagonal across the matrix from the top left to the bottom right based on the 1s as possible.**

Below shows the flow of how the `VBA` solution works through the problem.  In my final `Python` solution I'm not worried about the flow matching, just the final output.
Starting data set:

```
           Part
          a b c d e f
machine a 1 1 0 1 0 0
        b 0 0 1 0 1 0
        c 1 0 0 1 0 0
        d 0 0 1 0 0 1
        e 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Step 1, Need columns decreasing and rows increasing number of 1s:

```
           Part
          c f d a e b
machine e 1 1 0 0 0 0
        d 1 1 0 0 0 0
        c 0 0 1 1 0 0
        b 1 0 0 0 1 0
        a 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Step 2, Part d moved, move machine b up to obtain the following matrix:

```
           Part
          c f d a e b
machine e 1 1 0 0 0 0
        d 1 1 0 0 0 0
        b 0 0 0 1 0 0
        c 1 0 1 0 1 0
        a 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Then part e was moved to obtain the following end matrix:

```
           Part
          c f e d a b
machine e 1 1 0 0 0 0
        d 1 1 0 0 0 0
        b 1 0 1 0 0 0
        c 0 0 0 1 1 0
        a 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

**As you can see, the final product is a diagonal of the 1s across the matrix.**

To put in in perspective, I've got thousands of part numbers to work with and the `VBA` solution shared in a spreadsheet can handle 350 at best but takes a LONG time (~30 min) to execute.

I have tried to search but it seems this kind of grouping which a mean/average isn't applicable doesn't seem to come up in the articles I could find.

I really appreciate the help in solving this.

Comment: I see someone voted to close by voting that it was 'too broad'.  I'm always interested in being a good member of SO and asking good questions.  For the voter of 'too broad', can you help me understand why you voted that way?

Comment: Probably because SO, is for more focused questions. Perhaps this is better asked in the https://datascience.stackexchange.com or the https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Note that I'm not the one that voted to close the question